# How to reset a forked repo to its original state without affecting previously done pull requests?

Tags: git, github, version-control

1-I forked a repository on github made some changes to it committed the changes then did a pull request to the origin repository.

2-Now, I want to start over from the original state of the forked repository commit some changes and than do another pull request.

My problem is whenever I try to reset the forked repository to its original state via this command:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

it automatically closes the pull request done in step 1.

My solution until now was to completely delete the forked repository from the settings menu and commit my changes, but it takes a lot of time and I was wondering if there's another more efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

When you create pull requests on Github you have the option to specify which branch from your repository you want merged into which branch on the upstream repository. It doesn't have to be **master->master**, it can be from any branch to any branch.

If you want to create a new pull request starting from scratch, simply start a new branch from `HEAD~1` (i'm guessing this means you only have a single commit since forking).

```
git branch newbranch HEAD~1
git checkout newbranch
```

Do your work and create a new pull request for that branch into the same branch as your first pull request.